# CakePHP SQL Error when trying to use loadModel

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

I have two controllers (Feeds & Items), on the Items add view, I want some information from the Feeds table visible to the user.

So in the Items Controller I'm trying to access the Feed model, everything I have come across recommends to use [loadModel](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3A%3AloadModel) but when I try to load the Items add view, I getting the following error:

*Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1*

*SQL Query: SHOW TABLES FROM*

Please note there is no relationship setup between these two tables.

Feed Model

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Feed extends AppModel {}
```

Item Model

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Item extends AppModel {}
```

Item Controller

```
App::uses('Feed','Model');
class ItemsController extends DirectResponseAppController {

      function add() {       

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

          $this->Item->create();
          if ($this->Item->save($this->request->data)) {

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your item has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
          }
          $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your item.'));

        } else {

          $this->loadModel('Feed');
          $xxx = $this->Feed->find('all');

        }
      }

}
```

Any help appreciated.

** EDIT **
After a bit more digging, the problem seems to be with this line:

```
$xxx = $this->Feed->find('all');
```

I'm just not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Feed is inside a plugin (DirectResponse), you must use loadModel like this:

```
$this->loadModel('DirectResponse.Feed');
```